# Particle は VS の when identifying ownership with the verb ある

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-は

Quick basic grammar question.

With respect to expressing ownership of an item using ある.  Am I correctly understanding the general meaning and particle use in the following sentences?

1. 私の辞書がありません　→　I do not have MY dictionary
2. 私は辞書がありません　→　I do not have a dictionary

I think the second example makes sense grammatically speaking, however I'm unsure if the first example is correct.  Can I use の in similar situations like this to express if a particular item belongs to me? Can I use it like this with いる as well?

For example:

1. 私の子供がいます　→　The child is mine
2. 私は子供がいます　→　I have a child

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to JLSE!  I replaced the rōmaji in your question with Japanese writing.  If you object to these changes, please feel free to click "edit" and roll them back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

私の辞書がありません　does NOT mean　"I do not have my dictionary."  This is a very common mistake among J-learners.  To us native speakers, it can ONLY mean "My dictionary is missing." as in "I brought my dictionary here but I can't find it now.  Where did it go?"

Yes, 私は辞書がありません　means "I do not have a dictionary."

私の子供がいます　does not mean "The child is mine."  It is not such a natural-sounding sentence but if anyone said it, it would mean "There is my kid."

Yes, 私は子供がいます　means "I have a child."

Comment: In what context would you use the Japanese word(s) for missing or unaccounted for? 欠落や行方不明？

Comment: That depends on the context but generally you can just say ~がない or ～が見つからない. 欠落 is way too formal and has more nuance than that, and 行方不明 is used with missing persons.